# Attempting to load Google sign-in pop, but hit with error: (auth/argument-error)

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an Angular application that utilizes Firebase for authentication. I'm encountering an error with the message FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error) in my app.component.ts file, specifically on line 31. I am trying to utilize the sign-in with Google option, but I am getting errors of the Firebase side. I know that I am connected to Firebase because I am able to deploy.

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private titleService: Title,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.titleService.setTitle('MPCS High School Points System');
  }

  title = 'MPCS High School Points System';

  async ngOnInit() {
    try {
      await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  signIn() {
    this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        // Sign-in successful
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle sign-in error
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }

  navigateTo(routeName: string) {
    this.router.navigate([routeName]);
  }

  isMenuOpen = false;

  toggleMenu() {
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; // No need for a separate import for RouterModule
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireModule, FIREBASE_OPTIONS } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';



// Third-party modules
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

// App modules
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import {GoogleAuthProvider} from "firebase/auth";
import {getAuth, signInWithPopup} from "@angular/fire/auth";

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AdminComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.router.config);
  }
}
```

Comment: I too have same issue, Did you find the root cause?